# Make nested query in FirebaseStore, so the second query uses output from the first query

Tags: android, database, firebase, async-await

Using FirebaseStore as a database in my android project.

Now I want to make a query on a document of my database and perform another query using the values I got from the first query.

Everytime I run this code, I got a nullpointer exception at the second query, as it start executing before getting the answer from the first query.

I need to make so the second query waits the answer from the first query with this code. How can you perform this?

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //Getting the TenantProfile.
        DocumentReference tenantProfile = db.collection(DataBasePath.USERS.getValue())
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

        tenantProfile.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                userProfile = documentSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
            }
        });

        //Making a query to all Tenant and looking for the candidates.
        CollectionReference userReference = db
                .collection(DataBasePath.USERS.getValue());
        LandlordProfile landlord = userProfile.getLandlord();

        Query tenantCandidateQuery = userReference
                .whereGreaterThan("tenant", "")
                .whereEqualTo("country",landlord.getTenantNation())
                .whereEqualTo("gender",landlord.getTenantGender())
                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", landlord.getTenantMinAge())
                .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age",landlord.getTenantMaxAge())
                ;
        tenantCandidates = null;
        tenantCandidateQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                        tenantCandidates.add(document.toObject(Profile.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I need to make this line `LandlordProfile landlord = userProfile.getLandlord();` wait for the answer from the first Query, how can you do this?